# Model contains Null Values for List Objects when data is sent from Javascript

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I am trying to Post Dynamically built data Model from Java script to Controller:

Following are my two Model Classes:

```
public class TestModel
{
    public TestModel()
    {
        lst = new List<SubCls>();
    }
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public List<SubCls> lst { get; set; }
}

public class SubCls
{
    public SubCls()
    {
    }
    public int SubID { get; set; }
    public string SubName { get; set; }
}
```

On Controller Side I have a function that takes TestModel Parameter:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult TestJS(TestModel modelobj, FormCollection formob)
{
}
```

In Java script i have following:

```
var lstsub = {
        SubID: 1,
        SubName: "Sub"
    };
    var modelobj = {
        ID: 1,
        Name: 'MyName',
        lst: [lstsub]
    };

    $.ajax({
        url: '@Url.Action("TestJS")',
        method: 'POST',
        data: modelobj,            
        sucess: function () { alert('Success'); }
    });
```

Now when this call reaches server, i can see the values populated in TestModel fields ID and Name, the lst field also has one object at 0 index **but the SubID and SubName fields of the list are 0 and Null.**

One other observation is that if i see the values in form collection then for lst field the keys are like lst[0][SubID] instead of lst[0].[SubID], so maybe that is why it is not being mapped correctly.

How can i correctly send this data from java script so that the list is populated with actual values.

Thanks

Comment: try removing the brackets.  [lstsub] to lstsub

Comment: No removing the bracket removes the array and the lst field at server becomes null (as opposed to value at 0 index with null properties when [] are provided)

Answer (score 0):

if that doesn't work try pushing to the array

```
var lstsub = [];
lstsub.push({
    SubID: 1,
    SubName: 'Sub'
});
```

Comment: This behaves exactly as the code mentioned in question. i.e. lst field has an object at 0 index but with default values, SubID=0 and SubName=Null

Answer (score 0):

You may need to add a setting to your ajax call e.g. traditional: true, dataType: json,

$.ajax({
        url: '@Url.Action("TestJS")',
        method: 'POST',
        traditional: true,
        dataType: json,
        data: modelobj,
        sucess: function () { alert('Success'); }
    });

Comment: Setting traditional: true does not solve the issue. Although the lst field is not null but it has no object (count=0)